# Python help and autocompletion functions in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I am new to python and I have installed it. I have got the basic program running. However I write program in notepad and then run it from command prompt.

Now I am using numpy and similar libraries and I would like to get help on what a function does, what it expects or maybe type a name of function and get auto completions like in MATLAB or 
similar IDEs, how can I do this, which tool/editor I can use?

Comment: Install visual studio code https://code.visualstudio.com/download, press shift+ctrl+p and select python package to install. That should give you access to docstrings if the imported libraries have it and autocomplete. About 40MB download.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

i use VS code with a python module installed https://code.visualstudio.com/